# C++ blocking flush

Tags: c++, linux, flush

I want to flush a file output stream (fstream). If I do it the usual way (flush()), the program does not wait until the contents of the file are actually written, it continues on. To illustrate the issue, consider the following scenario:

A requires B to write something to a file. B immediately returns upon completion of the task. Then, A accesses the file. Unfortunately, the B has finished before the OS actually managed to write the contents of the file. The file does not exist yet, A crashes.

So, is there something like a blocking flush?

Note that the issue does not arise when B writes to cout, and B's stdout is redirected to a file. Unfortunately, if B uses cout for other purposes, this workaround cannot be applied.

---

**EDIT:** I've found out that the problem lies somewhere else in the end. For those of you that are interested:

Short version is, that the file indeed did exist, but could not be read because another program was still writing to it.

Long version: Suppose we receive program A, which can be thought of as a "solution" to some algorithmic problem. The problem is on-line, meaning that the input must be provided to A in small chunks. To do this, we create a program B that communicates with A. Whenever A sends an answer, B sends the next input chunk. We run an interaction between A and B: we create a FIFO file (`mkfifo fifo`) and then `A < fifo | B > fifo`.

We want to capture the output of A and see if it matches some target output file `target.out`. One way to do this is to have B open a file stream (`fstream fout("test.out", fstream::out)`) and write everything it reads from A there. Another solution is this: `A < fifo | tee test.out | B > fifo`. After the interaction between A and B is done, we run `diff test.out target.out` to compare them.

Unfortunately, both of the solutions suffer the following problem: once A finishes, we immediately continue to the comparison. The `tee` or `B`, whichever is the author of `test.out`, need not have finished yet. If so, the file cannot be read (even though it exists, as many of you have pointed out).

Switching the order of A and B does not come into consideration, because we are capturing the return code of A, too. (Gotta report that the solution has crashed when it has crashed.)

Comment: Your explanation isn't quite clear (to me). Obviously the file exists when B calls Flush. Please add some code that illustrates the issue.

Comment: What OS is this on?  Typically the OS's filesystem has an integrated buffering layer so that even if the data isn't physically on disk yet, another program trying to read the file will still "see" it because the filesystem driver's read-routine knows to look in the filesystem's memory-cache before looking on the disk.

Comment: This is on linux, I did not test it on other OS.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The scenario you have described does not exist. If A accesses the file that B should have written, it will succeed even if the file does not yet exist on disk.

Answer (score 0):

For resileince against system crashes, you want the fsync/fdatasync  syscall.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync

From POSIX:

> The fsync() function shall request that all data for the open file
>   descriptor named by fildes is to be transferred to the storage device
>   associated with the file described by fildes. The nature of the
>   transfer is implementation-defined. The fsync() function shall not
>   return until the system has completed that action or until an error is
>   detected.

For simple IPC like you've described in the question, you don't need to do anything.

When A looks at info that B has fflushed to the system, it doesn't matter that the info hasn't made it to disk yet. A won't take it from the disk, it will take it from the system and the system will give it up to date info regardless of whether the data's been synced to permanent storage or not.

Comment: This just affects the OS file cache and is useful to make sure that the data is actually on disk (for e.g. transactional integrity in face of power loss), but the OS already provides a coherent view of the content of the file across processes even without syncing to disk.

Comment: Ah ok now I see the edit.